# Facebook get friend list issue in Unity

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I use Graph API Explorer User Data Permissions and check "user_friends" ,

use FQL Query to fill in "/me/friends", I can get it below:

```
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "xxx",
            "id": "750725034949941"
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
          "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/1569963793218579/friends?limit=25&offset=25&          __after_id=enc_AexiIZhvUUA7W93CyCbEKqop8pgwMeZe0FVYg2fNQIrAxRs7nDvv1nuUG_aoKR8JOxUf29FXPlsfg9xVsGgDDToj"
        },
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 1
        }
      }
```

But I use Unity app to call FB.Login("user_friends,email,public_actions",callback);

then call FB.API("/me/friends")

I only get the result below:

```
{"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":1}}
```

How to modify C# code to get friendList detail?

Comment: why you never accept answers ?

Comment: To chouaib: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: If someone answers your question and you find that the answer solves your problem, please check it as `Accepted answer` and upvote it by clicking the up arrow

Comment: Ok,I already know the Accepted button just,I will check later problems

Comment: I change "Graph API Explorer" to my app name in Graph API Explorer Application combobox,
it will get the same result.
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 1
  }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That´s a new feature of v2.0: You only get the friends who authorized your App too. If no other friend authorized your App, data will be empty. Also, FQL is deprecated.